# Stream Subscriptions in initState()...do you need to call dispose()?

Tags: flutter, dart

If you set up a stream in initState() for Streambuilder do you have to call dispose()?

If I had a screen using Streambuilder and I navigate to a different screen does the stream stay active or is it automatically destroyed?

Every time you navigate from a screen, it is removed from the widget tree and when you navigate back to it, initState() runs again. Because of this behavior I am assuming the stream automatically gets destroyed when you navigate away from the screen?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you push to another widget (screen) the previous one is kept alive. The navigation works as a Stack, each widget that is pushed comes on top of the other one and when you pop the top one gets removed.
So, when you navigate to another widget the previous one is alive and so is its children such as StreamBuilders. (To remove the the last screen and then navigate to another widget you can use "pushReplacement").

And also the initState runs only one time and thats when the widget is built so if you pop back to a widget it wont run initState.

Secondly, it is always recommended and safe to dispose all controllers of any kind in the dispose method so that it will be removed when it isn't needed so it won't take memory space anymore.

I hope you got your answer.

Comment: Ah okay, so if my stream is subscribed to firebase and I don't want to have unnecessary reads when I'm not on the screen, what would be the way for us to have the stream be active only when viewing the screen? I'm guessing it would be using pushReplacement every time?

Comment: I'm using DefaultTabController in my HomePage() and each screen subscribed to a stream is just the body of the Scaffold. I can't call pushReplacement to navigate between these widgets since they are just the body of the Scaffold of the HomepAge() depending on which TabBar is tapped.

Since the stream is set in initState() and initState() only runs once...I'm guessing it's not a good idea to call dispose?

Comment: Since you are using DefaultTabController the stream will be kept alive if you slide your screen. But if you really want to remove subscriptions in this scenario, you can use onTap method in AppBar to remove or initialize a controller that you need based on the page that you selected